# How to calculate the package price even if the item being out of stock?

Tags: magento-1.8, php, backend

When one of my package bundled product is out of stock the value of the package is 0, but I need it to calculate the correct value and show it, even if the bundle products are out of stock, the type of the package price is fixed . Anyone have any tips on how to make it calculate the price even products being out of stock?